# QGIS Labeling not working

Tags: qgis, labeling

Using Qgis 2.8
Trying to label a line/road layer, pull up the dialogue box, everything in the dialogue box seems to work except the labeling doesn't appear on the map. All of the labels don't work for any of the layers, which lead me to believe its something to do with QGIS settings. The shapefiles themselves output just fine.

Simply when I click 'apply changes' nothing happens, but otherwise I receive no errors saying that something on qgis is wrong. What could be the issue?

Comment: I reloaded the shapefile and the labeling appeared...still mystified as to why....